# Bizarre behaviour in a nested form - need <%= not <%

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms

I'm using rails 3.1.3

I was trying to make a nested form - I made it work in the end, so I've got all the accepts_nested_attributes_for bits right.

This is the form that worked:

```
<%= form_for(@article, :as => :article) do |f| %>

  ......some article fields in here

  <%= f.fields_for :article_site_permissions do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :name %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

The weird bit is that the line `<%= f.fields_for :article_site_permissions do |builder| %>` needed `<%=` not `<%`.  All the examples I've seen (eg http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast) can use `<%` not `<%=`.  Coincidently, later that day the same thing happened on a colleagues project, which prompted this question.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From rails 3.0 onwards `<%=` is the right thing to do (see the [release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#action-view)). The railscast you link to predates rails 3.0.